# Create dynamic uiview on double tap

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiviewcontroller

Hello fellow programmers., 
I want to create dynamic UIView of size 100X100 around my double click on Main UIView (Everytime I double click diffrant place). I totally don't have any idea about it. So can't provide any code for it. Anyone can help??

Comment: what you have tried so far ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  - (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
   UITouch *myTouch = [[touches allObjects] objectAtIndex: 0];
   CGPoint currentPos = [myTouch locationInView: self.view];
   NSLog(@"Point in myView: (%f,%f)", currentPos.x, currentPos.y);

  UIView*hover = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(currentPos.x - 50, currentPos.y - 50 , 100, 100)];

  hover.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];

 [self.view addSubview:hover];
}
```

Comment: Thanks SH_Khan, Sorry for this. I did it but i want to create uiview where i double click not on same position,

Comment: Thank you So much @Sh_Khan.

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(addDynamicView:)];
self.view.userInteractionEnabled = TRUE;
tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
```

adding the custom view

```
- (void)addDynamicView:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)aGesture{
    /** add view with specified frame **/
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(10, 10, 100, 100);
    UIView *lView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
    lView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    [self.view addSubview:lView];
}
```